# Starting/Stopping Java Service Classes

Tags: java, command-line, jetty, kill-process

I'm working on a Java application that I want to have run as a service application in Linux.

We use Jetty for one of our other applications and looking at its stop script it calls:

```
> java -jar start.jar --stop
```

How can I replicate this functionality on our new applications so the stop scripts don't have to be a Kill command?

Comment: Jetty is open source, you can check how it handles this and replicate that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've handled this before:

When your application/service starts, have it try to open a socket on a specific port and listen. If it successfully opens the port, it is the first instance and should run normally. If it is the second instance (the one with the `--stop` flag), it will not be able to bind the port. In this case, the second instance should send a stop command to the first over the socket and then shut itself down.